# How to group values in a nested repeater? (using relationship and random generated records)

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

I have a table of questions and a table of alternatives corresponding to each question. I'm planning to build a questionnaire system (in **ASP.NET)** which select a few random questions from that total of questions.

I'm using the following SQL Statement to choose the random questions:

```
SELECT TOP (@maxQuestions) QuestionID, QuestionName FROM Questions WHERE CourseID = @CourseID ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Which populates a **DataTable** in a **DataSet** and data bind it to a **Repeater control** (the parent Repeater). What I need now is to get every alternative related only to the current random questions generated from the **query** above in a separate SQL Statement so that I can populate the **DataSet** with a new **DataTable**, add the relation between them two and data bind it to another **Repeater control** (the child repeater).

I don't know how to get only the alternatives related to the current random questions I generated. Otherwise, I get an error saying that I don't have all child values corresponding to the parent values and I can't group the alternatives inside the same question.

Can anyone give me a light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this in one of two ways.

1. Inside your outer repeater (assuming you are using a nested repeater approach), you would take the key value from the DataItem that links your questions, and then I would grab a new datatable and perform FindControl() on the inner repeater.  I would then databind to the inner repeater and use the AddHandler method if you need to perform some manipulation on the ItemDataBound.
2. Using a similar approach to #1, but if performance is an issue, I would consider grabbing a datatable (and optionally caching it) of all the related questions and using the datatable's select() method inside the inner repeater and following through with FindControl() and AddHandler.